# Code::Blocks is not taking in all the required inputs

Tags: c

I am new to programming and this website, so sorry if this question has been asked before. I recently started learning C from online sources. I was watching C's tutorial on freecodecamp.org's YouTube channel and during the input section of the video, I tried to input many data types as show in the video. The program skips over the grade part of the input. I don't know why it's the case.

Here is the code of what I have done -:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 

{ 

char name[25];

printf("Enter your name : ");
scanf("%s", name);
printf("\nYour name is : %s\n", name);

char grade;

printf("\nEnter your grade : ");
scanf("%c", &grade);
printf("\nYour grade is : %c", grade);

int age;

printf("\n\nEnter your age : ");
scanf("%d", &age);
printf("\nYou are %d years old.", age);


double gpa;

printf("\n\nEnter your gpa : ");
scanf("%lf", &gpa);                        /* lf is used in input and f in output */
printf("\nYour gpa is : %f\n", gpa);




return 0;

}
```

When I run the program, it skips over the grade portion and does not take in the grade as input. I tried to adjust it by putting the grade input on top of the code sequence and then it worked. But when I entered another input sequence of name, it returned back to the same problem.

Here is the output -:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBRxE.png)

I don't know why this is happening. I would be happy if someone can help me out here.

Thank You.

I tried the above and the result was what I have shown.

Note -: When I shifted the grade sequence in the code to the top, it works. I don't know why it's happening because I may not always input grade first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your name with `scanf` leaves the `\n` in the input buffer.

If you try to read the grade via

```
scanf("%c", &grade);
```

you will consume that `\n` instead of reading new input.

To avoid this, use

```
scanf(" %c", &grade);
```

(mind the space before `%c`). The space will cause `scanf` to skip any whitespace and then ask for new input.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. I am really happy that you guys are coming out to help a newbie like me.

Answer (score 0):

Write scan f two times in a row

```
printf("\nEnter your grade : ");
scanf("%c", &grade);
scanf("%c", &grade);
printf("\nYour grade is : %c", grade);
```

Basically when you hit enter it gets picked up into variable grade, because enter or new line is also a character.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution worked too. Thank You. It would have been great if I could accept both answers. Thank You both.

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to work with char and char[]. So when we need to accept multiple inputs based on char, you should use **fflush(stdin);** before scanning for an input. This will help you to accept all the inputs separately.

Comment: Thank You for the quick response. Can you tell me where do I need to put this command in the code?

Comment: ```fflush(stdin)``` is UB.

Comment: Follow up. It worked! Thanks a lot! Can you explain me how it worked and what this command means? Again. Thanks.

Comment: As you are working with char, everything for computer is accepted in form of chars, even pressing the enter or space bar key. So while you are trying to accept multiple inputs by pressing either of it, scanning this as input.
"fflush() is typically used for output stream only. Its purpose is to clear (or flush) the output buffer and move the buffered data to console (in case of stdout) or disk (in case of file output stream)"
For details you can follow this...
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/use-fflushstdin-c/

I hope this will help you...Thanks & Regards

Comment: The reason for *typically used for output stream only* is that the C standard clearly states this usage is undefined: (C11, 7.21.5.2 The fflush function) "If `stream` points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes ...; otherwise, the behavior is undefined." Therefore you should not suggest to use it this way.